# How can the div remain as display show on the next HTML page when it was showing on the previous HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In each of the 20 HTML pages, I have this div element with different content that is currently on display: none;. I used javascript to show or hide the div. On one of the HTML page, I can show this div (turns to display: block), and I have a button that allows me to click to the next div (next HTML page) and the previous div (prev HTML page). The problem I'm encountering here is the next page will reload which will show the div as display: none when really I want it to be on display: block because the previous HTML page had the div showing (was display: block).

One approach I was thinking of was when I click to show the div (to display: block) on one of the HTML page, the other 19 pages collectively will display: block until I hide the div (display: none). **Ideally, I would want this approach.**

The other approach I have been reading up on is saving the data of the site in a localStorage or cookie. So the next page can load that data and make the div display: block. I don't understand this and I don't know if it make sense for solving the problem I'm having.

Here is what I currently have:

HTML:

```
    <! -- omitted HTML code above and below this div -->
    <div id="container">
    <a name="index"></a>
    
    <a href="pgs/35.html#35" >
        <div class="button-fullscreen display-left-fullscreen">
            <div id="arrow-left-fullscreen"></div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="pgs/1.html#1" >
        <div class="button-fullscreen display-right-fullscreen">
            <div id="arrow-right-fullscreen"></div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <img id="artwork-fullscreen" src="img/team1.jpg" />
    <img id="fullscreen-exit" onclick="openFullscreen()" src="img/fullscreen_exit-white-24dp.svg">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function openFullscreen() {
  var x = document.getElementById("container");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {

      x.style.display = "block";

  } else {
      x.style.display = "none";

  }
}
```

Comment: Read up on single page applications, the url can change but you share the same DOM across all urls in your app.

Comment: ***I have 20 HTML pages with the same div that is currently on display: none;. I used javascript to open the div.*** No, you have 20 different `div` elements and a `div` can't be `open` or `closed`.

Comment: @AdrianBrand read up on single page app, and didn't think it's fit for what I'm going for. I'm going to stick to a multi-page app framework. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @ScottMarcus are <div> usually referred to as div, div elements, or div tags? Thanks!

Comment: Both. The tag is the text in the HTML that is parsed and the element is the object that is created in the DOM.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Not quite. The tag is what's between `<` and `>`, thus there is an opening tag and a closing tag for most elements. An element is from the opening tag to the closing tag and everything in between (including other nested elements, if any). These are HTML terms. The object that is created in the DOM is more correctly known as a "node" or "element *reference*" (not an actual element itself). In other words, "elements" are a purely HTML construct, which can be represented as objects/nodes in the DOM (Document Object Model), which is a purely JavaScript construct.

Comment: Understood the tag part. Will soak in the second half regarding the objects, not sure if I entirely understood it. Thanks for clarifying these points!

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this I can think about.
You can add a GET parameter to the URL and read it in javascript to determine, if this element should be on block or not. So, you URL can look something like this: `http://example.com/?block=true`
Just a quick and dirty example for it to get an idea:

```
var test;
const queryString = window.location.search;
queryString.split("?").map(function(elem){ test = elem.split("=") });
```

You should, of course also check, if the parameter is there. If not, you shouldn't display it.

Or you can use, as you said, the localStorage in order to store this value.
Something like this.

```
if(!!localStorage.getItem('isBlock')){
  element.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
}else{
  element.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
}

function onButtonClick(){
  localStorage.setItem('isBlock', 'true');
}
```

The `!!localStorage.getItem('isBlock')` has two purposes here. It checks, if the value is true or if it is null.
So `!!(true)` results in true, while `!!(false)` and `!!null` result in false.

The problem here is that you don't know the state of the previous page. So, when you click on the button to get to the previous page, the previous page doesn't know that you changed the button to block. So, you need to store the state of your application somewhere. The URL or localStorage are normally the places where you do something like this.

Comment: Attempted both, still very confused about it. For the first one, I'm unsure how to go about checking if the parameter is there. Does what is stored as test (test = elem.split("="); ) becomes the new value for var test?